how to make sure the VariableSizeList scrollTo always work
I am using the react-window https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window VariableSizeList scroll to to jump the last offset position. When user change the pdf scale ratio, then dispatch the new pdf scale. At the same time, refresh the VariableSizeList and scroll to the new offset. This is the listening code and scroll to new offset logic:
React.useEffect(() => {
      if (projAttr.pdfScale === 1 && cachedScale) {
        return;
      }
      setProjAttribute(projAttr);
      if (virtualListRef.current) {
        virtualListRef.current.resetAfterIndex(0, true);
        let curOffset = getCurPdfScrollOffset(projId, viewModel);
        let fullScreenOffset = getNewScaleOffsetPosition(
          projAttr.legacyPdfScale,
          projAttr.pdfScale,
          curOffset
        );
        if (fullScreenOffset) {
          setDocLoadTime();
          console.log("get the newOffset:" + fullScreenOffset);
          scrollToOffset(fullScreenOffset, virtualListRef);
          setCurPdfScrollOffset(
            fullScreenOffset,
            projId,
            viewModel,
            "project attribute update"
          );
        }
      }
    }, [projAttr, cachedScale]);

this is the code scroll to offset look like:
if (virtualListRef.current) {
    console.warn("trigger scrolltooffset:" + offset);
    virtualListRef.current.scrollTo(offset);
  }

now I found when I invoke the scroll to in the code after the VariableSizeList changed, it did not jump to the specify position, but when I invoke the scroll to with button click trigger. It jump correctly. why did this happen? it seems the VariableSizeList render async and I should invoke the action after the render complete. how to make sure the VariableSizeList render complete before invoke the scroll to function? Now I am using setTimeout to delay sometime to trigger the scroll:
setTimeout(() => {
                scrollToOffset(fullScreenOffset, virtualListRef);
              },1000);

any better way?

There is a scroll function in react-window and the rest is probably related to handling the state properly. Not sure about your use-case and what the list should do. But here is a Codesandbox demo that is using a list that will be scrolled to the bottom after every change.

this demo is too simple, my project pdf contains 600+ pages. I am not sure the page increase effect the render speed or not

Oh, OK, I couldn't make the demo more complicated because I don't know what your PDF code is doing. Maybe onItemsRendered prop & InfiniteLoader could help with your issue. It should be called after the items are available. There is a SO question to it - not sure if this helps but it seems like you could affect the scroll position with it. I have created another Codesanbox using refs.

I think the scroll will tell to the VariableSizeList  but today I think you way maybe correct. I will try to do like this.
